# structure HTML to allow 3 divs to float next to each other (without CSS)

Tags: html

Curious if this is still possible -- 3 divs aligned side by side horizontally, one on the left one in the middle and one on the right.

Possible to structure this for this to occur naturally **without** the use of CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>div 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>div 2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>div 3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. The default display value for `<div>` is `display: block`. Elements with block display cannot appear on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Not really doable without CSS. The easiest way to handle a scenario is to wrap the three divs in a container, then use `display: inline-block` on the three divs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `<span>` instead of  div. I think those default to display:inline-block.

Comment: Have you actually tried that? In several browsers? Or do you only think it works?